# Is it Kalman filter if the measurement model is dependent on the measurement?

Tags: filter, kalman-filter, estimation

I'm estimating parameters of a parabola `y = ax^2 + bx + c`, while measuring the `x,y` points. My states are `s = [a,b,c]` and my transition model is `s(k+1) = Fs(k) + v(k)`, where F is just an identity matrix. My measurement model is `z(k) = [x,y] = Hs(k) + w(k)`. Now it would seem that the measurement model would require EKF for the parabola, but the states `a,b,c` are not in nonlinear relation. The Jacobian H would look like `H = [x^2 x 1]`, leaving out the rows of zeros for x term. Since the states are not present, I would be inclined to call this linear Kalman filter. But the inclusion of the measured `x` value seems to invoke Extended Kalman filter. How would you approach this?

There is even this [paper](https://www.iiit.kit.edu/publ/mms_2010_357.pdf), which suggest use of EKF. But it just seems like plain KF.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct, just a linear Kalman Filter would be fine. The measurement model is linear in the states, so even though to determine the H matrix you square the x value, the measurement model is still linear.

I didn't read the paper that you linked to, but I can if you think that I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Thanks! No need to read the paper, it’s either wrong or they do something a little differently.

Comment: With the model that you're using, you might have more success using a batch least-squares algorithm if the states are constant.